AJV how to include a schema in another schema
I want to use one schema in another schema without manually typing out the fields.
I can do it for an array like so:
import schemaAccountInfo from './schemaAccountInfo';
const schemaAccount = {
  type: 'array',
  items: schemaAccountInfo,
}

Can't seem to figure it our for just an object:
import schemaAccountInfo from './schemaAccountInfo';

const schemaAccount = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    id: { type: 'string' },
    active: { type: 'boolean' },
    accountInfo: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: schemaAccountInfo, // problem here
    },
  },
  required: [
    'id',
  ],
  additionalProperties: false,
};


Your array version should also use the $ref syntax.
import schemaAccountInfo from './schemaAccountInfo';
const schemaAccount = {
  type: 'array',
  items: 
    $ref: schemaAccountInfo,
}

import schemaAccountInfo from './schemaAccountInfo';

const schemaAccount = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    id: { type: 'string' },
    active: { type: 'boolean' },
    accountInfo: {
      $ref: schemaAccountInfo, // problem here
    },
  },
  required: [
    'id',
  ],
  additionalProperties: false,
};

